# RecyclerView causes force stop while refreshing

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I am using a Recyclerview from this [library.](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5036)

When I refresh the recyclerview and scroll at the same time the app will force close.

```
public class NewsFeed extends Fragment implements MyDynamicRecyclerView.SwipeRefreshListener, MyDynamicRecyclerView.LoadMoreListener {

MyDynamicRecyclerView myRecyclerview;
NewsFeedAdapter testAdapter;
ArrayList<ProgramModel> modelArrayList;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
Dialog dialog;
int limit;
private boolean firstSwipe;


public NewsFeed() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("NewsFeedFragment", "Destroyed");
    if (dialog != null)
        dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("NewsFeedFragment", "Paused");
    if (dialog != null)
        dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.i("NewsFeedFragment", "Resumed");
    firstSwipe = false;
    if (checkInternetForNewsFeed() && firstSwipe) {
        removeItems();
        new FetchBooks(false).execute();
        firstSwipe = false;
        Log.d("Swipe", "First swipe");
    } else if (checkInternetForNewsFeed() && !firstSwipe) {
        fetchAllBooksByHeader();
        firstSwipe = true;
        Log.d("Swipe", "Not first swipe");
    } else {
        myRecyclerview.showInfoLayout();
    }

    getActivity().setTitle("Të gjithë");
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Log.i("NewsFeedFragment", "Created");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_feed_fragment_layout, container, false);

    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_layout);

    myRecyclerview = (MyDynamicRecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerview);

    modelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    testAdapter = new NewsFeedAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), modelArrayList, (AppCompatActivity) getActivity(), this, false);

    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    myRecyclerview.setScrollContainer(false);
    myRecyclerview.setBackgroundColor("#FFFFFF");
    myRecyclerview.setSwipeRefresh(true);
    myRecyclerview.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE);
    myRecyclerview.setLoadMore(true, linearLayoutManager);


    myRecyclerview.setLoadMoreListener(this);
    myRecyclerview.setOnRefreshListener(this);


    myRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myRecyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    myRecyclerview.setSimpleDivider(false);
    myRecyclerview.setAdapter(testAdapter);


    limit = 0;
    if (checkInternetForNewsFeed()) {
        firstSwipe = false;
        fetchAllBooksFromDB();
    } else {
        firstSwipe = true;
        myRecyclerview.showInfoLayout();
    }

    return v;
}

public void fetchAllBooksByHeader() {
    limit = 0;
    if (modelArrayList.size() >= 1) {
        removeItems();
    }

    new FetchBooks(true).execute();
    testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void fetchAllBooksFromDB() {
    if (modelArrayList.size() >= 1) {
        removeItems();
    }

    new FetchBooks(false).execute();
    testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addHeader() {
    if (modelArrayList.size() == 0)
        modelArrayList.add(new ProgramModel());
}

public void addItem(String title, String author, String imageName) {
    modelArrayList.add(new ProgramModel(title, author, imageName));
    testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeItems() {
    modelArrayList.clear();
    addHeader();
}

@Override
public void OnRefresh() {

    getActivity().setTitle("Të gjithë");
    limit = 0;
    if (checkInternetForNewsFeed() && firstSwipe) {
        removeItems();
        new FetchBooks(false).execute();
        firstSwipe = false;
        Log.d("Swipe", "First swipe");
    } else if (checkInternetForNewsFeed() && !firstSwipe) {
        removeItems();
        new FetchBooks(true).execute();
        Log.d("Swipe", "Not first swipe");
    } else {
        myRecyclerview.showInfoLayout();
    }

    myRecyclerview.stopSwipeRefresh();


}

private boolean checkInternetForNewsFeed() {
    if (new ConnectivityState(getActivity()).isConnected()) {
        myRecyclerview.hideInfoLayout();
        return true;
    } else {
        // Fonts for the title and the message of the content
        Typeface messageTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf");
        Typeface titleTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf");

        // Setting up the content
        myRecyclerview.setInfoIcon(R.drawable.warning_icon, "#000000");
        myRecyclerview.setInfoTitle("Nuk jeni i lidhur me internet.", 18, Color.GRAY, titleTypeface);
        myRecyclerview.setInfoMessage("Rifreskoni edhe njëherë për të kontrolluar aksesin në internet.", 13, Color.GRAY, messageTypeface);
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void OnLoadMore() {
    new FetchBooks(true).execute();
    MyDynamicToast.informationMessage(AppController.getInstance(), "...");
}

public static void hideLoadingDialogFromBookActivity(Dialog d) {
    d.hide();
}

private class FetchBooks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private boolean reload;

    FetchBooks(boolean reload) {
        this.reload = reload;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        getBooksFromDB();
        return null;
    }

    private void getBooksFromDB() {
        StringRequest requestBooks = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, AppConfig.URL_FETCH_BOOKS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = limit; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        if (i < (limit + 5)) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            String imageName = "http://ec2-52-39-232-168.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/files/books/" + jsonObject.getString("cover");
                            modelArrayList.add(new ProgramModel(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("author"), imageName));
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    limit += 5;
                    if (reload) {
                        testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    MyDynamicToast.errorMessage(AppController.getInstance(), "" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                MyDynamicToast.errorMessage(AppController.getInstance(), "Request did not work!");
            }
        });

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(requestBooks);

    }

}

}
```

So basically I add the onRefreshListener to the recyclerView and it calls the "onRefresh". Inside this class I have created an inner one which will fetch some data from a specific url and add items filled with data received from that url.
When I try to refresh while scrolling, it gives me this:

> 03-18 16:11:22.855 5970-5970/com.libraryhf.libraryharryfultz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.libraryhf.libraryharryfultz, PID: 5970
>                                                                                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 4(offset:4).state:10
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetchPositionWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:270)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTaskWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:324)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.flushTasksWithDeadline(GapWorker.java:337)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.prefetch(GapWorker.java:344)
>                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.GapWorker.run(GapWorker.java:370)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)

I looked it up in the internet and found some info that claimed this is an issue that google should fix. I have been trying for days to fix this and no results.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point me to the right direction: fix this or at least handle it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify your list after setting it on an adapter. Especially not from a different thread.

---

In `getBooksFromDB` you call `modelArrayList.add()` which is most likely the reason for your crash, since you modify the list backing your adapter from another thread.

While you do call `notifyDataSetChanged`, this gets called before you actually start modifying your list, since the modification happens in the background.

```
new FetchBooks(false).execute(); // runs in background and modifies list
testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // executes immediately
```

If you *need* to modify this list (which there most likely is no need to) you should notify the adapter of the change *immediately* and the change must occur *on the ui thread*.
Also you can update your adapter on *what* changed by using the `notifyItem*`methods, e.g. `notifyItemRangeInserted`. Or you can have a look at DiffUtil to help you with updating your adapter.

---

The most common way of handling list changes is by swapping the whole list backing your adapter, followed by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

Create a *new* list, put your items in it, then pass the new list to your adapter. In your adapter put something like...

```
void setBooks(List<Book> books) {
  mBooks = books; // swap the whole list
  notifyDataSetChanged(); // notify of change
}
```

...and you will not face this issue.

Comment: I don't really understand the first part of your explanation. So when should I can notifyDataSetChanged(), inside FetchBooks inner class or right after new FetchBooks(false).execute() ?

Comment: Neither. Calling it in your AsyncTask is the wrong thread, and calling it directly after starting the task executes _before_ you actually modify the list. You should, as mentioned, _not_ modify the list, but create a new one which you swap as a whole, or use different means like `notifyItemInserted` (but is a bit harder to implement)

Comment: I can not use notifyItemInserted because The RecyclerView library I am using does not have that function. Is there any othe way?

Comment: This is a method on the adapter, so it should be available. And you can always just swap the whole list as shown